# AxImp.exe not found when trying to build C# solution in MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am trying to build a legacy C# app developed on Windows for Linux.  I have Monodevelop 7.8.4 installed and am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.  The solution builds fine on Windows 10.

The one error so far I am seeing is this:

/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB3086: Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed (MSB3086)

Does anyone know what the solution to this might be?  I did some web searches but could not find anything relevant.  AxImp.exe is present on my Windows environment.

Comment: `Aximp.exe` is Windows only, there are no ActiveX controls on Linux or macOS.

Comment: "I am trying to build a legacy C# app developed on Windows for Linux." The only feasible option today is to port your app to .NET Core, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/